# How to copy a sharepoint list with Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I copy a sharepoint list in the same sharepoint environment with powershell.
I use the powershell modules "pnppowershell" or "SharepointOnline.CSOM".

Greetings, P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate you can copy/import list in SharePoint.

Refer the powershell.

```
[void] MoveSpoList() {
        # looping through the lists
        $csvInput = Import-Csv -Path '.\Lists.csv'
        foreach ($row in $csvInput) {
            try {

                # Connects SharePoint Online
                Connect-PnPOnline -Url $this.SourceUrl.Trim() -Interactive
                Get-PnPWeb

                $ListName = $row.ListName.Trim();
                $IsLookUpList = $row.IsLookUpList.Trim();
                Write-Host $ListName
                Write-Host $IsLookUpList

                #Getting List Template Name
                $timestamp = Get-Date -Format FileDateTimeUniversal
                $tempFile = './SourceListBackup/' + $ListName + $timestamp + '.xml';

                Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Handlers Lists -ListsToExtract $ListName -Out $tempFile

                #Adding Rows to List Template
                if ($IsLookUpList -eq 1) {
                    Add-PnPDataRowsToSiteTemplate -Path $tempFile -List $ListName -Query '<View></View>'
                }

                #Applying Template to Destination Site
                Connect-PnPOnline -Url $this.DestinationUrl.Trim() -Interactive
                Get-PnPWeb
                Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path $tempFile
            } catch {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Error ', ':', $Error[0].ToString();
                Start-Sleep 10
            }
        }
    }
```

I have explained in details in below article and code is available to download.

[Move SPO List](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/move-sharepoint-listlibrary-from-one-site-to-another-with-data-or-without-data/)